# Problema com o CORS

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, cors

Estou desenvolvendo uma api para uma plataforma de educação, e dai
criei as minhas rotas privadas e públicas. As publicas são para
criação e validação de token, para ai usar ele para acessar as rotas
privadas, porém o Cors, por algum motivo, está bloqueando as
requisições nas rotas privadas, não dando block nas rotas, mas sim na
requisição que o server faz. Queria saber o que poderia ser isso,
aqui vai o code com arquivo de rotas:

```
const express =require('express')
const routes = express.Router()
const {save,get,getById} = require('../api/user')
const {saveCategory,removeCategory,getCategory,getCategoryById,getTree} =require('../api/category')
const {saveArticles,removeArticles,getArticles,getArticlesById,getArticlesByCategory} =require('../api/articles')
const {signin,validateToken} = require('../api/utils/auth')
const {authenticate} =require('./passport')

routes.post('/signup',save)
routes.post('/signin',signin)
routes.post('/validateToken',validateToken)

routes.route('/users')
        .all(authenticate)
        .post(save)
        .get(get)

routes.route('/users/:id')
        .all(authenticate)
        .get(getById)
        .put(save)

routes.route('/categories')
        .all(authenticate)
        .get(getCategory)
        .post(saveCategory)
   
        // Rota tree deve vir antes de categories/id     

routes.route('/categories/tree')
        .all(authenticate)
        .get(getTree)

routes.route('/categories/:id')
        .all(authenticate)
        .get(getCategoryById)
        .put(saveCategory)
        .delete(removeCategory)


routes.route('/articles')
        .all(authenticate)
        .get(getArticles)
        .post(saveArticles)

routes.route('/articles/:id')
        .all(authenticate)
        .get(getArticlesById)
        .put(saveArticles)
        .delete(removeArticles)        
        
routes.route('/categories/:id/articles')
        .all(authenticate)
        .get(getArticlesByCategory)






module.exports =routes
```

E esse daqui é aonde eu chamo o cors:

```
const express =require('express')
const app = express()
const bodyParser =require('body-parser')
const consign = require('consign')
const db = require('./config/db')
const routes = require('./config/routes')
const cors =require('cors')



//app.use(cors)
//app.db=db
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(routes)
```

O método que da *block*, e chama o service de autenticação é o .All()

Dai se você tirar o metódo `All()`, as rotas voltam ao normal.

Comment: Descomente a linha: `app.use(cors)`

Comment: Ah sim tem outra coisa, a sua chamada está errada, deveria ser assim: `app.use(cors());`

Comment: tinha esquecido de descomentar no repositório,mas já fiz tudo isso e da na mesma

Comment: segue aqui o link do repositório:

https://github.com/BrunoSan123/ProjetosPara-Duvidas/blob/master/versao-inicial/backend/config/routes.js

Answer (score 1):

O cabeçalho `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, definido pelo middleware `cors` não configurado do `express` tem o valor `*`, que significa, basicamente "qualquer origem é válida", o que costuma ser suficiente para resolver a maior parte dos problemas simples de origem cruzada.

No entanto, para acessos em origem cruzada que requerem autenticação, quando `*` é enviado nesse cabeçalho, o navegador simplesmente bloqueia o envio de cookies e de vários cabeçalhos, entre eles o `Authorization`, que você deve estar usando justamente para fazer a autorização dos seus usuários com um token JWT...

Para contornar esse problema, no lugar de enviar um wildcard (`*`), você deve enviar ao usuário a origem da requisição em pré-voo dele. Por sorte, o middleware `cors` já resolve esse problema de maneira bem simples.

```js
app.use(cors({
  origin: true
});
```

Assim, quando você fizer uma requisição ao servidor a partir de um navegador, o navegador vai

- Enviar uma requisição do tipo `OPTIONS` dizendo a sua origem (o site que está fazendo o pedido, vamos chamar de https://origem.com).
- Receber uma resposta do servidor dizendo "As origens válidas são 'https://origem.com'"
- Tendo entendido que a origem em que o usuário está é válida para o envio de requisições em origem cruzada, enviar a verdadeira requisição para a API com a devida autorização correspondente.

Referência:

- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#examples_of_access_control_scenarios)
- [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuration-options)